# How do I not include scripts and clientlibs in an experience fragment when exporting to Adobe Target?

Tags: aem, aem-6

I'm trying to build an experience fragment (XF) template in AEM 6.5. We have some custom clientlibs that I want to include when designers are authoring the experience fragment but I don't want to include when the experience fragment is injected via Adobe Target as the clientlibs will already be included on the base page template.

I want the clientlibs on the XF template so components render properly while designing. I've tried building a new page component based on /libs/cq/experience-fragments/components/xfpage and then checking the runmode for author or publish and using the result of that in a data-sly-test to conditionally include them. But I think because the Export to Target option happens on Author, it's including the scripts in the html output when it's exported to Target.

How do I conditionally include clientlibs during authoring of an XF, but not include them when the experience fragment is exported to target and added to a page from there?

Comment: Try to use the `nocloudconfigs` selector. See https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-65/developing/extending-aem/experience-fragments.html. "By default, when you construct a Target HTML Offer, a request is sent to a custom Sling selector in AEM. This selector is called .nocloudconfigs.html . As its name implies, it creates a plain HTML rendering of an Experience Fragment, but does not include cloud configurations (which would be superfluous information)."

Comment: Thanks @ronnyfm I'll give it a look.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things you need to do in order to achieve this.

1. AEM offers the Link Rewriter Provider Interface. This is a ConsumerType interface that you can implement in your bundles, as a service.
   It bypasses the modifications AEM performs on internal links of an HTML offer as rendered from an Experience Fragment. This interface allows you to customize the process of rewriting internal HTML links to align with your business needs.
2. To use the interface you first need to create a bundle containing a new service component that implements the Link Rewriter Provider interface.

This service will be used to plug into the Experience Fragment Export to Target rewriting in order to have access to the various links.

```
import com.adobe.cq.xf.ExperienceFragmentLinkRewriterProvider;
import com.adobe.cq.xf.ExperienceFragmentVariation;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Service;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;

@Component
@Service
public class GeneralLinkRewriter implements ExperienceFragmentLinkRewriterProvider {

    @Override
    public String rewriteLink(String link, String tag, String attribute) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldRewrite(ExperienceFragmentVariation experienceFragment) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPriority() {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

> shouldRewrite

You need to indicate to the system whether it needs to rewrite the links when a call is made for Export to Target on a certain Experience Fragment variation. You do this by implementing the method:

> shouldRewrite(ExperienceFragmentVariation experienceFragment);

For example:

```
@Override
public boolean shouldRewrite(ExperienceFragmentVariation experienceFragment) {
    return experienceFragment.getPath().equals("/content/experience-fragment/master");
}
```

This method receives, as a parameter, the Experience Fragment Variation that the Export to Target system is currently rewriting.

In the example above, we would like to rewrite:

links present in ***src***

***href*** attributes only

for a specific Experience Fragment:
/content/experience-fragment/

Any other Experience Fragments that pass through the Export to Target system are ignored and not affected by changes implemented in this Service.

***rewriteLink***
For the Experience Fragment variation impacted by the rewriting process, it will then proceed to let the service handle the link rewriting. Everytime a link is encountered in the internal HTML, the following method is invoked:

```
rewriteLink(String link, String tag, String attribute)
```

As input, the method receives the parameters:

***link***

The String representation of the link that is currently being processed. This is usually a relative URL pointing to the resource on the author instance.

***tag***

The name of the HTML element that is currently being processed.

**attribute**
The exact attribute name.

If, for example, the Export to Target system is currently processing this element, you can define CSSInclude as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/etc.clientlibs/foundation/clientlibs/main.css" type="text/css">
```

The call to the rewriteLink() method is done using these parameters:

```
rewriteLink(link="/etc.clientlibs/foundation/clientlibs/main.css", tag="link", attribute="href" )
```

When you create the service you can make decisions based on the given input, and then rewrite the link accordingly.